Uniform functions on Riemann surfaces
I'm reading now J.F.Ritt's article "Prime and composite polynomials", and in the construction of section 2 he writes "Since $u$ is uniform on Riemann surface of $m$ sheets, and has exactly one pole, it's inverse to a rational function". Unfortunately, I don't understand "uniform" in this context and so don't understand, why is it true. Can you please help me

Sounds like some archaic terminology that nobody currently uses.

usually uniform in the older terminology means analytic and single-valued (in this case meromorphic since analytic on Riemann surfaces allows for poles)
